# Is there a line homomorphism to a disk?

Tags: general-topology

This is a question from an interview. I am confused about this problem. I said yes in that interview because I remember something about Hilbert curve(I mean, is there a line that can fill a square completely?), but I am not sure. Is it right?

Comment: It was the second best answer that could be given.

Comment: You probably mean a Peano curve? Those are not 1-1, only onto, so no homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

An homeomorphism between a line and a disk can’t exist as a line minus a point is disconnected while a disk minus a point is connected.

However it exists surjective continuous maps between a line an a disk.

For an example of a curve filling a square, you can have a look at [Lebesgue’s curve](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-curve-filling-a-square_lebesgue-example/). [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve?wprov=sfti1) is indeed another example.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean homeomorphism? Homomorphism doesn't make sense here.

There is no homeomorphism from a line onto a disk because the line becomes disconnected when you remove one point and that doesn't happen in  disk.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let a line $L$ be homeomorphic to a disk $B(x,R)$

Then excluding a point $y \in L$  we will have that $B(x,R) \setminus \{point\} $ will be homeomorphic to $L\setminus \{y\}$.

This cannot be true because then line minus a point is disconnected and the disk minus a point is still connected.